# [Measure theory]. Proof of inequality of integrals of simple function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, functions

I have a question regarding a proof in my textbook.
The theorem is as follows :
if {$f_n$} is an increasing sequence of non-negative simple functions and $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) \geq g(x), \forall x, x \in X $, where g is a non-negative simple function then

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int f_nd\mu \geq \int gd\mu$

My proof seems a little too simple compared to the one given in the book. ( I should point out than the one in the book is not at all intuitive for me ). My proof is something like this :

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) \geq g(x), \forall x, x \in X \implies \exists n_0, \forall n \geq n_0, f_n(x) \geq g(x)$

$\implies \int f_nd\mu \geq \int gd\mu$ This is using a previous theorem in the book that conserve the inequalities passing from simples functions to integrals, and since $f_n$ and $g$ are simple functions the inequality hold ( I think ). Then by taking the limit we get the desired result.

What do I miss or cut here ?

Comment: It's fine. Although usage of Monotone Convergence theorem would make for a shorter proof, it's still the same principle.

Comment: So this proof is rigorous enough ? In the book they consider two cases where $\int gd\mu$ is finite and not finite. Then they work by defining a new increasing set and work with the intersection of this set and the partition induced by the simple function g.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that there is a a problem in your proof, namely that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) \geq g(x)$ for  all $x \in X$ is supposed to imply $f_n(x) \geq g(x)$ for some $n$ and all $x \in X$. As a counterexample take $f_n$ the indicator function on $[0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ and for $g$ the indicator function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: One another difficulty: let $f_n(x) < g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x \in X$, but $\lim f_n = g$.

Comment: Ok that clearly shows my proof is wrong. How would you guys go about proving this in an intuitive way ?

Comment: Looks like I overlooked that part when I wrote my comment... Do you want a proof without MCT?